# What is the syntax to send an HTTP POST request with a bearer token with it?

Tags: node.js, request, postman

```
let requestOptionsStep5 = {
     'hostname': auth,
     'method': 'GET',
     'path': `16ac1a91f529`,
     'port': 443,
     'protocol': 'https:'
   };
```

I want to send a POST request to the auth server and I don't know where to pass the bearer token and its value to it.

Comment: Typically bearer tokens are passed in headers as `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it needs to be passed in the header like this:

[image]

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to add `Bearer Token` to request in POSTMAN:

[image]

1. One `Authorization` tab of your request;
2. Select type of authorization you need (`Bearer Token` in our case);
3. Insert your token in `Token` input.

It will add header to your request *automatically*:
[image]